How to set Azure MSAL SSO for my Nextjs14 app using Approuter and next-auth
I am building a nextjs 14 app which uses app router with src/app/.. structure Is using layout.tsx as entry point for my application.
I do not have pages folder or _app.tsx as mentioned in many articles.
For this i want to Single Sign On using Azure MSAL configuration with next-auth
I am confused with folder structure and the flow as all the articles I find is all over place, with no clear examples. Whats the best or easy way to setup this and correct folder structure?
I tried to follow the documentation on nextjs, next-auth and azure, but nothing is clear and end-to-end. I am more confused on project structure as most articles suggest with  pages folder or _app.tsx or the react-msal configuartion way

https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad

@soujanya Nekkanti Can you share your code in the question?

@soujanya Nekkanti Check this SO answer.

SO  In this the project/folder structure is not clear. It is missing few parts which is confusing with the usual nextjs starter template

@soujanya Nekkanti Try these steps to create a next.js project using the app router for correct folder structure. 1. npx create-next-app@latest myapp or you can directly create it by using npx create-next-app@latest myapp --typescript command.

@soujanya Nekkanti After creating the Next.js project using the commands provided, replace the src folder with the one from my GitHub repo repository in your project and install the packages listed in the package.json file.

I tried the below Next.js application using App Router and next-auth to set Azure MSAL SSO authentication.
Refer my GitHub repository for complete code.
Complete Project structure :

Code :
src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts :
The below code configured next-auth to use Azure AD for user authentication, manages token and session details, and ensures the environment is correctly configured with necessary Azure AD credentials.
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

const { AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID } =
  process.env;
if (!AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID || !AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET || !AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID) {
  throw new Error("The Azure AD environment variables are not set.");
}
const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      tenantId: AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, {
          access_token: account.access_token,
        });
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session) {
        session = Object.assign({}, session, {
          access_token: token.access_token,
        });
        console.log(session);
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

types/next-auth.d.ts :
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    access_token?: string;
  }
}

src/app/page.tsx :
import React from 'react';
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the Home Page</h1>
      <a href="/api/auth/signin">Login</a>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HomePage;

src/app/components/Header.tsx :
The Header component provides a user interface for managing authentication state, including displaying a welcome message when the user is logged in and offering a logout button, while handling the loading state appropriately.
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const Header = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const handleLogOutClick = async () => {
    try {
      await signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <header>
      {session ? (
        <>
          <p>Welcome, {session.user?.email || "User"}</p>
          <button onClick={handleLogOutClick}>Logout</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>You are not logged in</p>
      )}
    </header>
  );
};
export default Header;

.env.local :
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID=<clienyID>
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET=<clientSecret>
AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID=<tenantID>
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

I added the below URL in the App registration > Authentication > Web redirect URI as shown below,
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad


Output :
I successfully logged in and out using the Login and Logout buttons.




Reference :  SO answer by @Seeker.

Thank you for sharing this. It works as expected. But I am looking to make few tweaks like not having any pre-login page instead if the user is not authenticated should directly redirect to microsoft sign in page instead

@soujanyaNekkanti I will try and let you know.

And does any one have an idea of how we can do a silent token acquire in next-auth like we do for when using msal-react by using the acquireTokenSilent??

@soujanyaNekkanti  Please raise a new question with detailed information, so that can better assist you.
